# Как подключить mysql на js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как подключить MySQL в js. Как потом взаимодействовать с БД?

Comment: сервер, клиент?

Comment: Использую node js.

Comment: ORM(фреймворк) или напрямую sql ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mysql

Comment: Думаю напрямую!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp осилите или нужен перевод?

Comment: С английским не знаком, но попробую переводчиком. Но если есть на русском, буду благодарен.

Comment: нету, но я верю в вас) сам mysql, сама база какой-нибудь phpmyadmin(и базу создать и sql сформировать) есть? если нет - начните с установки mysql и phpmyadmin. какая операционка?

Comment: windows 10. Уже подключил. Все удачно, сейчас буду гуглить как получать данные из бд, или создавать\записывать.

Comment: phpmyadmin(и базу создать и sql сформировать)